# Can't push to heroku, distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available

Tags: python, mysql, heroku, flask

When attempting to push a flask-mysql python app. Is there anyway to conditionally tell the flask-mysql extension to use distribute >= 0.6.28? I included it in the requirements file and it installs, but still no dice when I hit the flask-mysql line inside of requirements.txt, it still tries to go for 0.6.27.

```
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python (from Flask-MySQL==1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FM%2FMySQL-python%2FMySQL-python-1.2.4c1.zip
         Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
           The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
           and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
           install a more recent version first, using
           'easy_install -U distribute'.

           (Currently using distribute 0.6.27 (/tmp/build_1w0z6sg73qbm/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg))
           Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
           The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,

       and can't be installed while this script is running. Please

       install a more recent version first, using

       'easy_install -U distribute'.



       (Currently using distribute 0.6.27 (/tmp/build_1w0z6sg73qbm/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg))

       ----------------------------------------
       Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 2 in /tmp/build_1w0z6sg73qbm/.heroku/venv/build/MySQL-python
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

Comment: You could try specifying an older version of MySQL-Python in your requirements file, and see if that then gets you a corresponding lower  version requirement for distribute.

Comment: In my requirements all I have is flask-mysql. Then it goes and tries to download mysql-python. How would I change that?

Comment: Well, you could try an earlier version of `flask-mysql`.

Comment: I had to clone a custom build pack and add distribute manually. Now it works. https://github.com/djohnsonm/heroku-buildpack-python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, I ran:

```
easy_install -U distribute
```

This upgraded distribute and then it installed OK.